# Naming text boxes in vb2010

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an application in vb2010 that requires a lot of text boxes.  Renaming each text box to have a unique identifier is proving very time-consuming. eg renaming TextBox1 to txtName1 is a lengthy process when there are lots of them.

Is there any way of speeding this up to give a user-friendly name with a unique ID number? Or is it just a question of ploughing through each one?

Comment: You can use **Find** / **Replace** in visual studio :)

Comment: If you have **Notepad++** this will be much easier. Notepad++ has a regular expression (regex) Find/Replace facility.

Answer (score 3):

Always try to assign a meaningful name to the control. If you follow this approach, you will find that computer cannot help with that, so it needs to be done manually. In your case, how does it know that `TextBox1` need to identify a `name`?

`txtName1` is not a good name for a control either, because **a)** it does not tell developer whose name is that and **b)** what's `1`? Does it mean the first part of the name, i.e. first name? Or name of the first person in a list? Proper name would be something like `txtCustomerFirstName` or `txtFirstCustomerFullName` (for **a)** and **b)** respectively), unless you have other considerations, such as keeping control's name as short as possible, match database field name, or another reason.

**Source:** I developed an enterprise-class application for insurance management with more than a 1000 textboxes, and am a primary support contact for any issues with it at the moment. From my experience, naming of controls is *NOT* where you spend most of the time.

As a side note, if you manually rename a control via designer, it also renames all its usages in code. It greatly reduces work needed to be done.

Comment: To assign a meaningful name, you can still do it programmatically in Excel vba ;-)

Comment: @bonCodigo: I don't think OP is asking about Excel. Regarding your WinForms answer, I think OP is asking about design-time change of Name, not in runtime. End goal is to ease project navigation and make more maintainable code.

Comment: Doubt I mentioned about run time. What I posted is merely two solutions that can assign unique names to x number of controls either in a form or a sheet... which indefinitely design mode.plus why would someone want to change control name in run time?

Answer (score 2):

Try : Editing as I am front of a PC now ;) It's indeed good to consider what above answer says. Anyway, here is something to know. When you are adding a textbox or any other Control in Excel sheet, it becomes an `Embedded` type like the image shows.

[image]

> [Usually if you want to check if a Control is a **Textbox** we can use **17**, which represents **msoTextBox**, the **mso shape type enum** for a TextBox. However those embedded **Form type controls (Forms 2.0)** are Shapes and do not differentiate each type with different values but common **12**, the type enum which stands for **msoMixedShapes**. Following 2nd code works for a `FORM`, however it's hard to get the same settled for Excel sheet Shapes (textboxes)... Click on the link to view all the **MsoShapeType Enumeration**.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa432678%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

If you really want meaningful names to be given to the Shape textboxes in the Sheet, here is one way to do:

```
Option Explicit

Sub reNameMeaningfully()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim arrNames As Variant
Dim i As Integer

    arrNames = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("D2:D7").Value)
    '-- assuming that you have exact number of names for the exact number of controls

    For i = LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames)
        Set shp = Sheets(1).Shapes(i)
        '-- we can't check Type here. So we check if default-name begins with Text
        If shp.Name Like "Text*" Then
            shp.Name = arrNames(i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

If those tecboxes are in a `Form` then try this: You can use the same logic to put all names in a range and then iterate through that ;)

```
Dim Cont as Control
Dim i as integer
i = 1
 For Each Cont In Me.Controls
     If TypeName(Cont) = "TextBox" Then 
          Cont.name = "txt" & i '-- Rename 
     End If 
 Next Cont
```

Comment: @Trevor check this out :) but for first code you need to put the correct syntax.

Comment: @Trevor `txt1` is  a sample and there are more classical way of doing this as well ;) as mentioned it's recommended to take a look the other answer as well. Anyway I just updated with a better solution.