# MS Access - Do forms have a 'children' property?

Tags: ms-access

I know Access forms have a property called `parent`, so is there any way of referencing their children? Ideally something like:

`Forms!frmParentForm.Children`

Comment: By "children", do you mean the controls forms contain?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210660(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cycle through a Form's Controls collection and determine the type of control as follows:

```
Dim f As Form
Set f = Forms!MyForm
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In f.Controls
  If TypeOf ctl Is SubForm Then
    MsgBox "subform: " & ctl.Name
  ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
    MsgBox "Textbox: " & ctl.Name
  Else
     ' test for more control types / do something
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the controls on a form are "children" of that form and can be referenced by name, as in `Me.Text1` for a text box. If you're looking for *forms* that are children of other forms by virtue of their being used in a Subform control then you could find them by enumerating the controls on the parent form, identifying the Subform controls (`.ControlType=112`), and then retrieving their `.SourceObject` property values.

Comment: This may also help for enumerating all controls, including those of subforms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344649/how-to-loop-through-all-controls-in-a-form-including-controls-in-a-subform-ac