# VBA Several UserForms export to Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

In my Workbook i have several identical UserForms. Only the name is different.
For Example WKA1 / WKA2 / WKS1 / WKS2 / PM1 / PM2 and some more.

Now i want if i click on the CommandButton on the UserForm, that the Data in the TextBoxes will be saved on a extra Worksheet. I want that with a seperate Macro, so that i code for the CommandButton looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Save_UF_Data
    [NameOfUF].Hide
End Sub
```

The Problem is, i don´t know how to write in the Macro "Save_UF_Data" that it always takes the TextBox from the UF which is open.

I already tried it with:

```
Me.Controls("TextBox1")
```

I hope someone can show me how i have to write the code that my macro will work for every UserForm in my Workbook.

This is my Macro so far:

```
Public Sub Save_UF_Data()
     Dim lastrow As Long
     Dim a As Integer
     Dim ws As Worksheet

     Set ws = Worksheet("UserForm_Data")
     lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     a = 1

     Do
         ws.Range("A" & lastrow).Value = Me.Controls("Label" & a)    ' How do i have to change this part that it takes the value from the userform which is open?
         a = a + 1
         lastrow = lastrow + 1
     Loop Until a = 25
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the calling form Object as Parameter to the Sub:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Save_UF_Data(Me)
    [NameOfUF].Hide
End Sub
```

And the Sub would look like:

```
Public Sub Save_UF_Data(frm As UserForm)
    Debug.Print frm.Controls("Textbox1")
    (...)
End Sub
```

Have a look to [How to loop through all controls in a form, including controls in a subform - Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344649/how-to-loop-through-all-controls-in-a-form-including-controls-in-a-subform-ac) to learn how to access the controls of a form

Comment: fine solution +). *Side note to Diem:* as all userforms are identical (possibly referring to different sheets only), it should considered to load several *instances* of the same userform (being actually a class ).